# PAM http module to allow login with an http request

Tags: linux, authentication, unix, debian, pam

I'm working on a project to make a system to manage, create and start debian image for lab exam of my university (with PXE).
I have to make a PAM module to allow login with the credentials generated by my system. I would like to make login with a simple http request with username and password.
I found a project on Github called [pam-http](https://github.com/1nfiniteloop/pam-http) but this module allows login with only userID. 
How I can make it? Thank you for any advice!